# Filtering in date range

Tags: php, silverstripe

I try to build custom search form and filter results in some range of dates:

```
       $form = BootstrapForm::create (
            $this,
            'LetterSearchForm',
            FieldList::create (
            DateField::create('Sent_After','Sent After'),
            DateField::create('Sent_Befor','Sent Before')
            ...
            ),
            ...
       );



    public function index (SS_HTTPRequest $request)
    {
       $letters = Letter::get()->sort('DateUpload');

       if($search = $request->getVar('Sender')) {
        $letters = $letters->filter(array(
            'Sender:PartialMatch' => $search
        ));
        }
        if ( $search1 = $request->getVar('Sent_After') && $search2 = $request->getVar('Sent_Befor')) 
         {
              What must be here?
       }

    }

}
```

Can I use here something like WithinRangeFilter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any range filter, but according to [the documentation](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3/developer_guides/model/searchfilters/) you could use something like:

```
$dateFilteredList = $letters->filter(array(
    'DateUpload:LessThanOrEqual' => $search2,  // Sent_Befor
    'DateUpload:GreaterThanOrEqual' => $search1 // Sent_After
));
```

I made a few assumptions with the code above:

- `DateUpload` is the date field you're trying to filter on.
- The date format supplied by the form is already database friendly, ie yyyy-mm-dd (eg 2017-09-05)

You may need to edit it accordingly.

Hope that is what you're looking for :)